# if ($('.single-featured').width() < $(document).width())

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-resizing

I hope i got a simple question for you here. I went through google and stackoverflow search section, but hadnt quite the luck with solution ideas on my problem.

My problem is following, i need a banner to change second class if the width of the picture should dropt below the width size of the document. Generally i would use media queries but since it alawys depends just on the size of the picture i dont know how else i can get this to work then with js or jquery.

I don't rly know why it dosn't work. I executed all the errors i got on the console of Chrome and everyone that appeared on my editor... I generally use only html and css and can edit already existing js and jqueries. But this here is one of few codes i wrote on my own and i am kinda stuck...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.single-featured').resize(function(){

          if ($('.single-featured').width() < $(document).width())  {
               $('.single-featured').removeClass('thumb-vh');
               $('.single-featured').addClass('thumb-auto');
          }
          else {
               $('.single-featured').removeClass('thumb-auto');
               $('.single-featured').addClass('thumb-vh');

           }
   });
});
```

I appreciate any kind of solutions or explenations on that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. `resize` doesn't fire on individual elements, it fires on `window`, so `$(window).resize(...)`, not `$('.single-featured').resize(...)`.
2. To get the width of the window, you want `$(window).width()`, not `$(document).width()`.

---

Side note: It's not a good idea to constantly re-query the DOM. Do the query only when the results may have changed, and then remember the result:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
//    ^^^^^^
        var featured = $('.single-featured');
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if (featured.width() < $(window).width()) {
//                               ^^^^^^
            featured.removeClass('thumb-vh');
            featured.addClass('thumb-auto');
        } else {
            featured.removeClass('thumb-auto');
            featured.addClass('thumb-vh');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: As i said i generally use Media queries wen styling. But the problem dost depend on the window size alone but more on the size of an element. And i don't recall anything in media queries that alows me to say "hey if picture or block is below/higher the width of actual screen then add/remove this" If it would just only depend on the window size i woudnt consider js at all.

Comment: @AkumuDesu: Yeah, good point, I was forgetting the relative nature of it. Hopefully the rest of it is useful.

Comment: Ah and regarding the dom. I kinda thought about it to set it as a `var` but i thought it dosnt rly matter since its just a short code where i have the overview of the code. Thanks for that advice.

Comment: @AkumuDesu: You get a **lot** of `resize` events while the window is being resized. It's one of the rare places where it's worth thinking about performance up front, like `mousemove`. Meanwhile, did this solve your problem? If not, what's the remaining issue?

Comment: Crowder it helped me quite well. Thanks for the help. Just one question left. Is it a rule/law or why can't i use the class of my element  in this part `$(window).resize(function() {` instead of `window` ?
Edit: nvm i over read that first part of your post... was kinda in a hurry and overlooked it ^^